# Write a program that prompts the user to enter a year and the first day of the year, then displays a calendar by constructing HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript (and mostly new to programming in general). This assignment, as stated in the title, was to take inputs for year and first day of the year via prompt from a user, and construct a calendar in the form of an HTML table.

I got started with code from the same type of problem written in Java, and have *translated* it; however, I cannot get anything to return to the browser.

My desk and forehead are currently bloody and I would really appreciate any help on what I'm doing incorrectly, and/or missing.

Below are both my js code and html.:

```
    "use strict";
function getCalendar(year, day)
{
        var firstDayOfMonth;
        var result;

        //Find a number of the first day
        switch (day) 
        {
            case 0 : firstDayOfMonth = "Sunday"; break;
            case 1 : firstDayOfMonth = "Monday"; break;
            case 2 : firstDayOfMonth = "Tuesday"; break;
            case 3 : firstDayOfMonth = "Wednesday"; break;
            case 4 : firstDayOfMonth = "Thursday"; break;
            case 5 : firstDayOfMonth = "Friday"; break;
            case 6 : firstDayOfMonth = "Saturday"; break;
            default : result = "<p>Error: there is no such day of week</p>";
        }

        //Whether the year is a leap year
        function isLeapYear(year) 
        {
           return ((year % 4 === 0) && (year % 100 !== 0)) || (year % 400 === 0);
        }


        //Display the calendar
        for (var month = 1; month <= 12; month++) 
        {

            //Proper spacing between months
            if (firstDayOfMonth == 0)
                result += "<br />";
            else
                result += "<br /><br />");

            //Get name of the month
            var monthString = "";
            switch (month) 
            {
                case 1  : monthString = "January"; break;
                case 2  : monthString = "February"; break;
                case 3  : monthString = "March"; break;
                case 4  : monthString = "April"; break;
                case 5  : monthString = "May"; break;
                case 6  : monthString = "June"; break;
                case 7  : monthString = "July"; break;
                case 8  : monthString = "August"; break;
                case 9  : monthString = "September"; break;
                case 10 : monthString = "October"; break;
                case 11 : monthString = "November"; break;
                case 12 : monthString = "December"; break;
            }


            //Display the heading of the month  
            result += "<table border='1'><tr><th>" + " " + monthString + " " + year + "</th></tr><tr><th>Sun</th><th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th><th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th></tr>";

            //Find the length of the month
            var length = 30 + ((month + (month / 8.0)) % 2);
            if (month == 2) //Adjust February length
                if (isLeapYear)
                    length -= 1; //Leap year
                else
                    length -= 2; //Non-leap year

            var counter = 1; //Counter to determine end of the week

            //Display blank space before first day
            for (var i = 0; i < firstDayOfMonth; i++) 
            {
                result += "<td>"  "</td>";
                counter++;
            }

            //Display days
            for (var day = 1; day <= length; day++) 
            {
                result += "<td>" + day + "</td>";
                result += (counter++ % 7 != 0) ? "  " : "<br />");
            }

            //Determine the first day of the next month
            firstDayOfMonth = (firstDayOfMonth + length) % 7;

        }
        result += "</table>";
    return result;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>Calendar</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="getCalendar.js">
</script>
 </head>

  <body>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var yearInt = parseInt(prompt("Enter year", 2016));
var dayInt = parseInt(prompt("Enter the first day of the year. 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, ..., and 6 for Saturday", 5));
document.writeln(getCalendar(yearInt, dayInt));

</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are basically syntactical erros!

missed the ""  **+**"" here

```
result += "<td>"  "</td>";
```

an extra braces - **)** in the following two lines

```
result += "<br /><br />)";
result += (counter++ % 7 != 0) ? "  " : "<br />)";
```

```js
var yearInt = parseInt(prompt("Enter year", 2016));
var dayInt = parseInt(prompt("Enter the first day of the year. 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday, ..., and 6 for Saturday", 5));
document.writeln(getCalendar(yearInt, dayInt));



  "use strict";
function getCalendar(year, day)
{
        var firstDayOfMonth;
        var result;

        //Find a number of the first day
        switch (day) 
        {
            case 0 : firstDayOfMonth = "Sunday"; break;
            case 1 : firstDayOfMonth = "Monday"; break;
            case 2 : firstDayOfMonth = "Tuesday"; break;
            case 3 : firstDayOfMonth = "Wednesday"; break;
            case 4 : firstDayOfMonth = "Thursday"; break;
            case 5 : firstDayOfMonth = "Friday"; break;
            case 6 : firstDayOfMonth = "Saturday"; break;
            default : result = "<p>Error: there is no such day of week</p>";
        }

        //Whether the year is a leap year
        function isLeapYear(year) 
        {
           return ((year % 4 === 0) && (year % 100 !== 0)) || (year % 400 === 0);
        }


        //Display the calendar
        for (var month = 1; month <= 12; month++) 
        {

            //Proper spacing between months
            if (firstDayOfMonth == 0)
                result += "<br />";
            else
                result += "<br /><br />";

            //Get name of the month
            var monthString = "";
            switch (month) 
            {
                case 1  : monthString = "January"; break;
                case 2  : monthString = "February"; break;
                case 3  : monthString = "March"; break;
                case 4  : monthString = "April"; break;
                case 5  : monthString = "May"; break;
                case 6  : monthString = "June"; break;
                case 7  : monthString = "July"; break;
                case 8  : monthString = "August"; break;
                case 9  : monthString = "September"; break;
                case 10 : monthString = "October"; break;
                case 11 : monthString = "November"; break;
                case 12 : monthString = "December"; break;
            }


            //Display the heading of the month  
            result += "<table border='1'><tr><th>" + " " + monthString + " " + year + "</th></tr><tr><th>Sun</th><th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th><th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th><th>Sat</th></tr>";

            //Find the length of the month
            var length = 30 + ((month + (month / 8.0)) % 2);
            if (month == 2) //Adjust February length
                if (isLeapYear)
                    length -= 1; //Leap year
                else
                    length -= 2; //Non-leap year

            var counter = 1; //Counter to determine end of the week

            //Display blank space before first day
            for (var i = 0; i < firstDayOfMonth; i++) 
            {
                result += "<td>"  +"</td>";
                counter++;
            }

            //Display days
            for (var day = 1; day <= length; day++) 
            {
                result += "<td>" + day + "</td>";
                result += (counter++ % 7 != 0) ? "  " : "<br />";
            }

            //Determine the first day of the next month
            firstDayOfMonth = (firstDayOfMonth + length) % 7;

        }
        result += "</table>";
    return result;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>Calendar</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="getCalendar.js">
</script>
 </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

When you get error in javascript, try using the Console!

To open the dedicated **Console panel**, either:

- Press Ctrl+Shift+J (Windows / Linux) or Cmd+Opt+J (Mac).
- If DevTools is already open, press the Console button.
  When you open the Console panel, the Console drawer collapses automatically.

The JavaScript Console provides two primary functions for developers testing web pages and applications. It is a place to:

- Log diagnostic information in the development process.
- A shell prompt which can be used to interact with the document and DevTools.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Awesome, it works! Thank you! I guess I had been looking at it too long... Thanks also for the advice on the console! I'm not sure why it is returning "undefined" before the table, so I'll have to look into that, as well as the formatting of the table itself.